# python subprocess in background with stdin

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I've looked at the docs for the subprocess module and replacing spawn1 with P_NOWAIT, but I don't see how to use this and also write data to stdin.  That is, if I call with

```
pid = Popen(...).pid
```

As the docs suggest, then I where do I communicate with the stdin PIPE.  Here's some example code

File 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# testing how to run a processin the background while writing to stdin
#
import subprocess
data = "".join([str(i) for i in range(0,200)])
p = subprocess.Popen(['./b.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(data)
print "code after communicate"
```

File 2 ('./b.py')

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import time
data = sys.stdin.readlines()
print "background process started"
time.sleep(10)
print "background process done"
```

So, the effect I'd like to achieve is that running the first file (f.py) would print this:

```
background process started
code after communicate
background process done
```

However, what I see instead is that "code after communicate" is printed after "background process done".  So it seems that p.communicate is blocking until after the background process finishes, how can I prevent this while still writing to stdin?

Comment: "Popen.communicate(input=None)
Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate." The communicate method is inherently blocking. Use p.stdout etc directly. Your thread can either block to fill/empty the stdout/stdin buffers of the program, or it can not block, in which case you would have to fill/drain them manually.

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses my question.  Sorry if I'm missing something.  You say to use p.stdout directly, but in my case I don't care about output, I'm interested in writing to the input of the process and then continuing along without waiting for the process to end.

Comment: I meant stdin. And you can't just "write to the input and carry on", because the input has a finite size buffer. Python has no way of knowing whether your `data` string is going to exceed the size of the buffer. Therefore, there has to be a process feeding the bytes of data to the subprocess.

Comment: I mean, you could do `p = subprocess.Popen(...); p.stdin.write(data); print "code after"`, but there's no guarantee that `p.stdin.write` won't block for arbitrary subprocess programs. (The subprocess runs immediately after the call to Popen, all that communicate does is mimic a simultaneous `stdout.read`, `stdin.write`)

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand better now.  And, as you say, just using p.stdin.write(data) seems to be giving me the effect I want.  I guess if you had put this into an answer, I would accept it!  Thanks for the help.